# What's wrong with this combination-generating recursion?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, combinations, permutation, powerset

I have the following code:

```js
const findMult_3 = (num) => {
  const powerset = (set) => {
    const combinations = []
    const combine = (prefix, chars) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        combinations.push(prefix + chars[i])
        combine(prefix + chars[i], chars.slice(i + 1))
      }
    }
    combine('', set)
    return combinations
  }

  const allCombinations = powerset(num.toString().split(''))
  console.log(allCombinations)

}
findMult_3(362)
```

I would expect this to work, however, with the input of `362`, the function console logs:

```
[ '3', '36', '362', '32', '6', '62', '2' ]
```

It's missing variants like `63, 23, 26` etc. It seems the `slice` call is to blame?

Comment: I guess the issue is with `chars.slice(i+1)`. Since for `2`, `i` will be 2, it will only point to characters ahead

Comment: @Rajesh What are you suggesting?

Comment: The [powerset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset) contains sub*sets*, and sets are not ordered. Your output is to be expected for a `powerset` function…

Comment: @ischnmn should be `chars.slice(0, i) + chars.slice(i+1)` probably

Answer (score 1):

Still not 100% sure what the issue was with the `slice` call, but I fixed it by sidestepping the issue and avoiding mutating my arrays:

```js
const findMult_3 = (num) => {

  const powerset = (set) => {
    const combinations = []
    const combine = (prefix, chars) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        combinations.push(prefix + chars[i])
        combine(prefix + chars[i], chars.filter((x, ind) => ind !== i))
      }
    }
    combine('', set)
    return combinations
  }
  
  const allCombinations = powerset(num.toString().split(''))

  console.log(allCombinations)

}

findMult_3(362)
```

Note the use of `filter` instead of `splice`, maintaining immutability.

Comment: Because if the first character is `6`, `slice(i + 1)` will return the following characters (`[2]`) while only removing 6 results in `[3, 2]`

Answer (score -1):

I found the problem, duplicate the array (to c), and then remove the element you are combining with:

```
const findMult_3 = (num) => {
  const powerset = (set) => {
    const combinations = []
    const combine = (prefix, chars) => {
      console.log(chars);
      for (let i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        combinations.push(prefix + chars[i])
        var c = chars.slice();
        c.splice(i,1);
        combine(prefix + chars[i],  c);
      }
    }
    combine('', set)
    return combinations
  }

  const allCombinations = powerset(num.toString().split(''));
  console.log(allCombinations);
```